# Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 USB freezes on Startup screen

Tags: boot

I'm not exactly an expert when it comes to linux.

Anyway, I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 onto an old machine I use as a test platform. It will reach the screen that gives me the options to install Ubuntu, check disk etc but then it freezes. I let it sit for maybe 3 or so minutes then it gave me green gibberish text on the top of the screen. Not sure exactly what's going on. The desktop boots fine with PFsense on the HDD.

Comment: The first thing you should try: compare the md5 hash of your iso to the ones in http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/MD5SUMS. It **might** be a bad download.

Comment: Could your clarify you question. What exactly installer doing while freezing, I mean on what step or after what step? Could you make a photo of your frozen screen. Are you able to run **Try Ubuntu without install** without errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can try pressing `F6` in the boot screen of the image and selecting the `nomodeset` option. Other options added may be necessary.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Comment: This doesn't seem to help. :/

Comment: This doesn't seem to help. :/